# SFDX: force:source:push with fields for the same object in different directories

Tags: salesforcedx

When I separate my code into packages, I occasionally have some fields for standard-objects (i.e. Account) in Package A and some other (different!) fields in Package B.

My folders in my working directory are basically structured like this:

```
.sfdx
.config
force-app
  main
    default
src
  package a
    classes
    objects
    flows
    ...
  package b
    classes
    objects
  package c
    classes
```

Including/excluding folders for `force:source:push` works fine, However if any package A contains the sub-folder `Account` with some fields, any subfolder `Account` in another (subsequent, determined by the order of appearence in my `sfdx-project.json`) package is ignored.

Can anybody think of an solution besides dragging all the customizings on accounts from all packages to a shared package?

Edit: I am on version sfdx-cli/6.29.0-0a2482692c (darwin-x64) node-v8.9.4

Comment: This used to work in previous versions, I think. Have you tried reaching [Wade Wegner](https://twitter.com/WadeWegner)?

Comment: No, I did not. But I will, thank you for pointing me there :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can still reproduce this, however I also found a workaround. Since it works for me and only takes a couple of seconds (per package), I can "accept it as an answer".

If you put your package-src-dir (package a, package b, etc in my example) in your `.forceignore` and only have **one** package that contains the fields for the duplicated object "active" per `force:source:push` command, the metadata gets pushed and all dependencies work. After repeating the process multiple times (depending on the number of packages with fields on the duplicate object), you can savely keep all packages "active" in your .forceignore, as long as you never update/alter the metadata of the duplicate sObject in two packages at a time.

Hope this helps other people with the same issue.